# PrimeNG: Growl disappears when redirect

Tags: angular, primeng, growl

I have an Edit page. On "Update" button click, it redirects to "Search" page. During redirect I also need to show "Successfully update!" message using growl, but it disappears during redirect.

I am using following code in Edit page template:

```
<p-growl [(value)]="msgs" ></p-growl>
```

The growl appears fine if I don't redirect.

Comment: You can to try put <p-growl> in Search component and pass a parameter in link when navigate to Search component, where a parameter is the message

Comment: Did you try to use p-growl on redirected page?

Answer (score 0):

Try with timeout

```
setTimeout(() => {/*fire here the growl*/}, 400);
```

Another way is locate growl outside the router-outlet